# How to click ListView and then open new class that play Youtube

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api, android-youtube-api

I have example how to play youtube from [this link](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2013/06/simple-example-using-youtube-android.html) It's look work for me and next I have main project and I create new class and copy that to new class and I try to use switch case to call youtube.class but It's error. Please advice and help my problem. thank a lot.

Sample Code:

```
    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private ListView listView;
private ListViewAdapter listViewAdapter;

private Animation animation;
private LayoutAnimationController layoutAnimationController;

private ArrayList<ListEntry> entries;
private Handler handler;
private Thread thread;

private int[] drawables = {
        R.drawable.images_01,
        R.drawable.images_02,
        R.drawable.images_03
};

private String[] titles = {
        "Test - 1",
        "Test - 2",
        "Test - 3"
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // View Matching
    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.main_listView);

    //data
    entries = new ArrayList<ListEntry>();

    // add data from project
    for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++){
        ListEntry listEntry = new ListEntry();
        listEntry.setTitle(titles[i]);
        listEntry.setDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(drawables[i]));
        entries.add(listEntry);
    }

    // setup adapter
    listViewAdapter = new ListViewAdapter();
    listView.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);
    listView.setLayoutAnimation(layoutAnimationController);

    //event
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long id) {

            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    Intent intent0 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, part1Activity.class);
                    startActivity(intent0);
                    break;

                case 1:
                    Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, part2Activity.class);
                    startActivity(intent1);
                    break;

                case 2:
                    Intent intent2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, part1Activity.class);
                    startActivity(intent2);
                    break;                       
            }

           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Loading....", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
        }
    });
}

    private class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private ListViewHolder holder;

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return entries.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int i) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int i) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

            //create view
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.listview_layout, null);

            // view matching
            holder = new ListViewHolder();
            holder.image = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.listview_item_image);
            holder.title = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.listview_item_title);

            //view setting
            //set title
            if (entries.get(position).getTitle() != null) {
                holder.title.setText(entries.get(position).getTitle());
            }

            //set image
            if (entries.get(position).getDrawable() != null) {
                holder.image.setImageDrawable(entries.get(position).getDrawable());
            }

            return convertView;
            }

        private class ListViewHolder {

            public ImageView image;
            public TextView title;
        }
    }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Comment: What types of error you are getting. Please show us your logcat.

Comment: As posted the code now make some effort to post logcat error also. :) \

Comment: "I create new class and copy that to new class and I try to use switch case to call youtube.class but It's error" What is the error?

Answer (score 0):

In your adapter class change your `getItem` and `getItemId` methods as below:

```
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return entries.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }
```

Also make sure you have [Register your app using YouTube Android Player API and obtain API Key](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2013/06/register-your-app-using-youtube-android.html)